# How do I add RtMidi.cpp and RtMidi.h files to Visual Studio 2019 to my project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, external-links

I'm trying to create a project that makes use of the `RtMidi` Classes. However, I have been having difficulty adding these the `RtMidi.cpp` and `RtMidi.h` files in a way that I can call the classes " `RtMidiIn, RtMidiOut`" etc.
I have tried :

Adding the source and header file directly to my project
I have tries using the Linking via the properties tab.

There really isn't much online that I have found.

Answer (score 0):

To use RtMidi Classes,  you need to follow the steps below:

1. Copy RtMidi.cpp and RtMidi.h file to the project file.
2. Right click on your project -> add existing item.
3. Add #include "RtMidi.h".